# feature mappings and SVMs

Tags: svm

I have a question being relatively new to SVMs. Suppose I have kernel $K(x,y)=\phi(x)^T\phi(y)$ for some feature mapping and a set of support vectors $\{ x_i \}$. Is there any way of finding the reverse projection of a linear combination of the projections of  $\{ x_i \}$ in the projected space, that is any $w$ such that

$$
\phi(w) = \sum_i \lambda_i \phi(x_i)
$$

for any choice of $\lambda_i$? Any general observations, results or specific cases would be of interest here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there is a general theory around this but the following appears to work in some cases. If you pre-multiply by $\phi^T(z)$ you get

$$
K(z,w) = \sum_i \lambda_i K(z,z_i)
$$

which you can then solve for $w$ given sufficient values of $z$. Effectively resembles a projection problem.